# RxJava2 filter List<Object>

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to filter a List with RxJava2 such that each item (object) in the list should pass a validation check and I get a resulting List with only items that pass that test. For instance if my Object had the following structure,

```
class MyClassA {
    int value1;
    int value2;
}
```

I want to only get the list of items where the `value2` is 10.

I have an API call function that returns an Observable of List, i.e. `Observable<List<MyClassA>>` as follows,

```
apiService.getListObservable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

and I would like to have the output filtered, so I tried adding a `.filter()` operator to the above but it seems to require a `Predicate<List<MyClassA>>` instead of just a `MyClassA` object with which I can check and allow only ones where `value2 == 10`.

I'm pretty new to RxJava and RxJava2 and seems like I'm missing something basic here?

TIA

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can unroll the list and then collect up those entries that passed the filter:

```
apiService.getListObservable()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
.flatMapIterable(new Function<List<MyClassA>, List<MyClassA>>() {
    @Override public List<MyClassA> apply(List<MyClassA> v) {
        return v;
    }
})
.filter(new Predicate<MyClassA>() {
    @Override public boolean test(MyClassA v) {
        return v.value2 == 10;
    }
})
.toList()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: could you please expand the lambda's to pre Java 8 code? would really help to see it that way

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the below. It demonstrates the ways to print just the filtered objects OR the lists that contain filtered objects. Here the filtering logic is to retain the `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`s that have even numbers in right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // print raw output
    getListObservable().subscribe(System.out::println);

    // print the objects post filtering
    getListObservable().flatMap(v -> Observable.from(v)).filter(p -> p.getRight()%2==0).subscribe(System.out::println);

    // print the list refined with only filtered objects
    getListObservable().flatMap(v -> Observable.just(v.stream().filter(p -> p.getRight()%2==0).collect(Collectors.toList()))).subscribe(System.out::println);

}

private static Observable<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> getListObservable() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
                list.add(Pair.of(i, j));
            }
            subscriber.onNext(list);
        }
    });

}
```

Output with contents of observable:

```
[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4)]
[(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
[(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)]
[(3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4)]
[(4,0), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)]
```

Output to contain only filtered objects:

```
(0,0)
(0,2)
(0,4)
(1,0)
(1,2)
(1,4)
(2,0)
(2,2)
(2,4)
(3,0)
(3,2)
(3,4)
(4,0)
(4,2)
(4,4)
```

Output to contain the lists that contain only filtered objects.

```
[(0,0), (0,2), (0,4)]
[(1,0), (1,2), (1,4)]
[(2,0), (2,2), (2,4)]
[(3,0), (3,2), (3,4)]
[(4,0), (4,2), (4,4)]
```