# How do you iterate over a list within an Observable in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am currently learning the very basics of RxJava/RxAndroid and have attempted to create a very basic Retrofit test application.

I am using RxJava 1.2.6 for this example.

However, I have not been able to find any clear examples of how to perform functions on the objects of a list that is **within** the Observable object.

E.g. If I have the following POJOs

```
public class AgencyResponse {

    private List<Agency> agencies;
    private int total;
    private int count;
    private int offset;

    public List<Agency> getAgencies() {
        return agencies;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }
}
```

As well as

```
public class Agency {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String abbrev;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }
}
```

---

How is it possible to map a function (for an example, print the  `getName()` of each `Agency` within the List) when the Observable object is the class that contains the list. I.e. `Observable<AgencyResponse>`

A real world and hopefully clearer example of this is below:

```java
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

 private TextView textView; // Code to populate this omitted

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Create Retrofit service
  LaunchLibService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(LaunchLibService.class, LaunchLibService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);

  //getAgencyList returns Observable<AgencyResponse>
  service.getAgencyList()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .map(AgencyResponse::getAgencies) // Gets the List<Agency> but how do I iterate over each object and print?
   .subscribe();
 }
}
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42215321/61158

Comment: Provide which version of RxJava.

Comment: This is using RxJava 1.2.6 - I will update the question

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd - That did indeed help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was solved using the following - I had been missing a `flatMapIterable` that would give access to the `Agency` object.

```
LaunchLibService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(LaunchLibService.class, LaunchLibService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
        service.getAgencyList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(AgencyResponse::getAgencies) // Gets the List<Agency> but how do I iterate over each object
                .flatMapIterable(agencyResponse -> agencyResponse)
                .map(Agency::getName)
                .subscribe(s -> textView.append(s + "\n"));
```